# Django Jinja output first element of list and then start for loop from second

Tags: python, html, css, django, jinja2

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to output first picture of the model in the first div and all the other in the second div.
I googled and didn't find any solutions. I'm sure that my solution is awful a bit.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="{{ carousels[0].image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>

{% for carousel in carousels([1]) %}
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{ carousel.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

View:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    carousels = Carousel.objects.all()
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,
                   'carousels': carousels})
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using jinja with django?

Comment: I'm sure, that example of code won't work, that's just how I imagine it to be

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jinja, then you can just use regular slicing (`[1:]` for "everything starting from the second item"):

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="{{ carousels[0].image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>

{% for carousel in carousels[1:] %}
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{ carousel.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The analogue in vanilla Django templates is the [`slice` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for carousel in carousels|slice:"1:" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine for a first approach of jinja

```
{% for carousel in carousels %}
{% if forloop.counter == 0 %}
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="{{ carousel.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{ carousel.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `{% if forloop.counter == 0 %}` doesn't work. It would be `{{ loop.counter0 }}` no?

Comment: But they're using `jinja2`